# Do I recover my .5 lumens when changing trust to delete a trustline?

Tags: accounts, trustline, base-reserve

I wanted to hold and trade 5 assets. It will cost me 2.5 XLM in the min-reserve to create these trustlines alone. If I am done with 2 assets and now want to only hold 3, I can delete 2 trustlines. Does my account get credited with 1 XLM?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You do not pay XLM, you just "freeze" XLM. Once you delete a trustline, it is "unfrozen".

Comment: When a trustline is established, the account balance is not changed. You just can't spent (transfer/trade) those frozen 0.5 XLM. Read more on fees and minimum account balance [here](https://www.stellar.org/developers/guides/concepts/fees.html#minimum-account-balance).

Answer (score 1):

Trustlines, Offers, Signers, and Data Values are called **subentries**. Each subentry *locks* 0.5 XLM from your account for the **min_reserve**.

When you remove a subentry from your account, the corresponding XLM balance is **unlocked** and you can use it. This is described in more detail [here](https://www.stellar.org/developers/guides/concepts/fees.html#minimum-account-balance), quoting:

> **Minimum Account Balance**
>
> All Stellar accounts must maintain a minimum balance of lumens. Any transaction that would reduce an account’s balance to less than the minimum will be rejected with an `INSUFFICIENT_BALANCE` error.
>
> The minimum balance is calculated using the **base reserve**, which is **0.5 XLM**:
>
> `(2 + # of entries) × base reserve`
>
> The minimum balance for a basic account is `2 × base reserve`. Each additional entry costs the base reserve.